# Replace First N Occurrences in the String

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace

How can I replace first `N` occurrences of many whitespaces and tabs in the following string:

```
07/12/2017  11:01 AM             21523 filename with s p a c  e  s.js
```

I am expecting the following result:

```
07/12/2017|11:01|AM|21523|filename with s p a c  e  s.js
```

I know not very elegant option only via calling replace `N` times on the same string

```
.replace(/\s+/, "|").replace(/\s+/, "|").replace(/\s+/, "|");
```

Worth to mention that I'm going to run this on near 1,000,000 lines so performance matters.

Comment: @stealththeninja Op wants to only replace the first 4 occurrences in the strings, thus leaving the spaces in the file name intact.

Comment: `g` will replace everything. But i need to replace only first `n` occurrences

Comment: smells like you can use a loop of some sort

Answer (score 9):

Probably something like this:

```
var txt = "07/12/2017  11:01 AM             21523 filename with s p a c  e  s.js";

var n = 0, N = 4;
newTxt = txt.replace(/\s+/g, match => n++ < N ? "|" : match);

newTxt; // "07/12/2017|11:01|AM|21523|filename with s p a c  e  s.js"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a counter and decrement it.

```js
var string = '07/12/2017  11:01 AM             21523 filename with s p a c  e  s.js',
    n = 4,
    result = string.replace(/\s+/g, s => n ? (n--, '|') : s);
    
console.log(result);
```

You could replace the ternary expression with one with logical AND and OR.

```js
var string = '07/12/2017  11:01 AM             21523 filename with s p a c  e  s.js',
    n = 4,
    result = string.replace(/\s+/g, s => n && n-- && '|' || s);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Derek and Nina provide great answers for dynamically replacing N whitespace groups. If N is static, the non-whitespace token (`\S`) can be used to match and keep the groups between whitespace:

`.replace(/\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+/, '|$1|$2|')`

Answer (score 2):

Some answers here are really good already, but since you say you want speed, I'd go with a single while, like this:

```js
var logLine = '07/12/2017  11:01 AM             21523 filename with s p a c  e  s.js';
var N = 4;
while(--N + 1){
  logLine = logLine.replace(/\s+/, '|');
}
console.log(logLine);
```

Here's on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2bxpygjr/

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with something like this. Though I kinda like Derek's answer so I'll look his up and understand what he/she does in it.

```
var mytext = "some text separated by spaces and spaces and more spaces";
var iterationCount = 4;
while(iterationCount > 0)
  {
    mytext = mytext.replace(" ", "");
    iterationCount--;
  }
return mytext;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about recursive version of you own solution?

```
function repalceLeadSpaces(str, substitution, n) {
    n = n || 0;
    if (!str || n <= 0) {
        return str;
    }
    str = str.replace(/\s+/, substitution);
    return n === 1 ? str : repalceLeadSpaces(str, substitution, n - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

- [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on whitespace, using a capturing group to retain the spacing;
- use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to replace the first N whitespace elements with `|`;
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the parts back together

```js
const str = '07/12/2017  11:01 AM             21523 filename with s p a c  e  s.js'

const N = 4
const result = str.split(/(\s+)/).map((v, i) => i % 2 == 0 || i >= 2*N ? v : '|').join('')

console.log(result)
```