# How to change (manipulate) char string depend on giving value

Tags: javascript, console-application, console.log

i want to ask how to manipulate char in string depends on giving value

my string

```
"---x---x---x------x"
```

when im input a value = 2

char "x" was changed to "o" in 2 times

my expected value is

```
"---o---o---x------x"
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, have you tried anything so far to solve this problem (please provide your attempt)? You can look at using a `for` loop to loop through each character in your string and use that to build a new string, using an `o` instead of an `x` if you encounter an `x` while also keeping a counter to see how many x's you've seen so far.

Comment: Yes, I've used various ways such as for and loop. but I don't understand how to replace the same char in string based on giving value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230492/replace-first-n-occurrences-in-the-string):

```
var str = "---x---x---x------x"
var n = 0
var N = 2
var newStr = str.replace(/x/g,s => n++<N ? 'o' : s)
```

Comment: As a beginner I didn't realize there were simple ways to solve this problem :D

Answer (score 0):

```
const x = "---x---x---x------x";
let input = 2;

let output = [];
for (const dashes of x.split("x")) {
  output.push(dashes);
  if (input > 0) {
    input--;
    output.push("o");
  } else {
    output.push("x");
  }
}
output.pop();
output = output.join("");

console.log({ output });
```

Comment: in line 8 i want to ask, "input --" what for?

Comment: I am decreasing the input to add only the desired number of `o`

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop over the and replace `x` with `o` until `value` becomes `0`(which is falsy value)

```js
let str = "---x---x---x------x";
let value = 2;

while (value--) {
  str = str.replace("x", "o");
}

console.log(str);
```